# flutter ChangeNotifierProxyProvider - dependency between states and notify widgets

Tags: flutter, provider, state-management

I have User model and some other models (PlayModel, Stats) depends on User.
For example,

```
// User data will be stored in cloud.
User {
  String userId;
  RawStats rawStats;
}
// Model for Play page. When User plays, update raw stats.
PlayModel {
  void updateRawStats();
}
// Model for Stats page. Advanced stats.
Stats {
  Stats stats;
  void computeMoreStats(rawStats);
}

providers: [
        ChangeNotifierProvider<User>(          
            builder: (context) => User()),
        ChangeNotifierProxyProvider<User, PlayModel>(
          initialBuilder: (_) => PlayModel(),
          builder: (_, user, playModel) => playModel..update(user),
        ),
        ChangeNotifierProxyProvider<User, Stats>(
          initialBuilder: (_) => Stats(),
          builder: (_, user, stats) => stats..update(user),
        ),
    ],
```

(This is simplified version, but the real example will be more complex)

RawStats are updated based on user's play, and user can see more advanced stats on Stats page.

1. If userId is updated, both Play page and Stats page should be updated.
2. Play page can update User's RawStats, and Stats page should be updated.

If I run notifyListeners() in playModel..update(user),
Play page will be updated every time it updates the RawStats.

Is this a right approach or is my design flawed?
Should I divide userId and rawStats?

Comment: It will depend entirely in the complexity of your app and the data, you should divide your system where one object logic friend entirely of other object value, what I don't fully understand is your second point saying Play page can update User's RawStats, does that mean the provider that depends on the user can change the user?

Comment: Yes, if the user plays, user's raw stats (e.g., scores, hit etc) will be updated. The reason I added the rawStats to User class is to gather all user related information in one class.

Comment: Well I'm not sure that is the best choice or approach, this way all the providers are codependent, and it will result in some spaghetti code were the provider down will affect the provider up and at the same time it will rebuild the proxyProvider, I don't know if I'm making myself clear

Comment: Thanks for the comment! I'll try to re-structure the data classes to reduce the dependencies.